# Kali Linux terminal offsetting the $

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

I messed around with my Kali terminal, and now the $ doesn't display properly. I've tried rebooting, and also reset the default terminal setting, but alas it's still messed up. Any ideas how I can reset it or fix this?

Video link showing issue using Vim on .bashrc:
https://youtu.be/C5SR19o4lT8

```
rinran@localhost:~$ printf '%s\n' "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${VIRTUAL_ENV:+($(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV)) }${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;34m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[;32m\]\[\033[01m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

[image: Terminal]

[image: .bashrc]

[image: prompt alternative]

[image: terminal font]

Comment: Check your `~/.bashrc` where you set the prompt, it's the `PS1` variable. Read `man bash`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `printf '%s\n' "$PS1"`.

Comment: @waltinator see edits in posts, note I have edited .bashrc to use:
PROMPT_ALTERNATIVE=oneline
NEWLINE_BEFORE_PROMPT=no

Comment: @terdon see edits

Comment: I think your issue is the non-monospace terminal font.

Comment: @pLumo see edit, I did notice that even if I change the font, hit OK, then hit OK again the font isn't applied on terminal restart. I tried with several different fonts.

Comment: In your screenshots its clearly not monospace.

Comment: it's not the problem only with `$`, as you can see all texts in the other screenshots are like that, so as pointed it's your terminal's font problem

Comment: Following on from @αғsнιη's comment: See for example the `:` after `localhost` in the prompt, and `=` after the upper-case letters at the start of the `.bashrc` file. This has nothing to do with the contents of `.bashrc` and everything to do with the choice of typeface used in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had to go into `/home/user/.config/qterminal.org/qterminal.ini` and edit `fontFamily` to

```
fontFamily=Monospace
```

If I did it in terminal it didn't save (even as root), so I used a GUI editor and saved it, fixed!